# evaluating remainders by using binomial

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am finding the remainder when $6^{88}$  is divided by $19$ , I applied Little theorem and obtained $9$, which is correct. My question is, can this be solved by using binomial theorem? I am not getting how to approach this.

Comment: Refer to.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.      For Mathjax tutorial

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
6^{88} &=& 36^{44} \\
&=& (38-2)^{44}\\
&=& 38^{44}-44\cdot 38^{43}\cdot 2 + ...-44\cdot 38 \cdot 2^{43} +2^{44}\\
&=& 19a+2^{44}
\end{eqnarray}

So you reduce your problem to $2^{44} = 16^{11} = (19-3)^{11} = 19b - 3^{11}$...

Comment: sir wait iam posting mine answer , can you tell me how you are writing  numbers  like 6^8  where is option iam not finding it

Comment: Click on edit on my post and you'll see

Comment: yes i see but how to get that  ?? menas how do i wru=ite myself what is option name

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what are you asking me

Comment: i wrote 6^88   and you write  6^88 neately  which option  is there  to write numbers in power just like you write

Comment: Put inside dollar signs

Comment: @provide a link iam new to site